# S3 to EC2 transfer is too slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to move a large file (~1.75GB) from S3 to EC2 instance in the same region.

Via AWS command line I can do it in ~13 seconds.

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/myfile.txt ~
```

`wget` from the same EC2 instance (if I make the file public) does it in 34 seconds.

```
wget https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myfile.txt
```

My application via REST API can download it with the same speed as `wget`.

The instance is m5a.2xlarge which should have "Up to 10 Gbps" network. If my math is right 10Gbps should be around 1 gigabyte per second, so under 2 seconds to get the file?

**UPD:** speedtest-cli shows 850Mbit/s.

```
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by BroadAspect (Ashburn, VA) [0.98 km]: 1.387 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 850.94 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 929.41 Mbit/s
```

**UPD2:** [Enhanced Networking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html) is enabled

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-30-0-196 ~]$ ethtool -i eth0
driver: ena
version: 2.0.2g
```

**UPD3:** Tried couple of more instance types. Smallest/cheapest ARM a1.medium and i3en.6xlarge (I/O optimized, "guaranteed" 25Gbps)

*Time to copy 1.75GB file from S3 to EC2 instance in the same region:*

```
|instance type|Network Gbps|aws s3 cp|wget|
|-------------|------------|---------|----|
|m5a.2xlarge  |  Up to 10  |   13    | 34 |
|a1.medium    |  Up to 10  |   26    | 34 |
|i3en.6xlarge |     25     |   7.5   | 18 |
```

What's interesting: switching to an IO-optimized instance improves the transfer speed, but it's still not anywhere near [file size]/[instance Gbps].

**UPD4:** AWS S3 configuration

AWS S3 CLI tool offers few [configurations options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html#cli-aws-help-s3-config) such as:

```
aws configure set default.s3.max_concurrent_requests 10
aws configure set default.s3.multipart_chunksize 8MB
```

Numbers above are defaults. After playing with these for a bit, the best combination I found for `m5a.2xlarge` is 3 concurrent requests, 180MB chunk size. That brings the download time down to 9 seconds or ~204MiB/sec. Better, but still quite far from (theoretical?) maximum.

Comment: `"Up to 10 Gbps"` is a range of values including (but not limited to) 0 Gbps. They don't guarantee a *consistent* 10 Gbps.

Comment: The speeds I see are pretty consistent and WAY under 10Gbps. Like 10x under?

Comment: `10Gbps` is a limit. It's like your router limit `10Gbps` but the throughput is only `1 Gbps` because of your internet provider.

Comment: If aws-cli is faster than wget, consistently, this suggests aws-cli is downloading the file in multiple parallel streams using byte-range requests. You aren't going to saturate your instance's connection with a single TCP stream.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html

Comment: Network speed isn't the only thing that affects download times: you also have to consider how fast you can store the file. In particular, if you're writing to an EBS filesystem it's going back out over the network. To quantify that, you can (1) time how long it takes to write a random stream of bytes, and (2) time how long it takes to download a file onto instance store (the m5d instances will give you a decent-sized instance store -- in fact, if you're just caching the files locally, they may be a good choice for your deployment).

Comment: And I should ask: the S3 bucket is in the same region as the EC2 instance?

Comment: @kdgregory yes, the same region. EBS is in play here for wget and aws s3 cp, but not for my app.

Comment: How is EBS not a factor for your app? Are you storing the file in memory?

Comment: Regardless, I think you need to isolate the different components that contribute to transfer time. Per speedcheck you certainly seem to be getting the expected throughput from your network.

Comment: Best Practices Design Patterns: Optimizing Amazon S3 Performance whitepaper
 https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/AmazonS3BestPractices.pdf

Comment: s3 is not the fastest way to store your file because the storage is distributed across multiple server. Use a EBS or EFS will bring you closer to 10 Gpbs of speed. There is also s3 throughput limit.

Comment: @Hamuel what is the s3 throughout limit?

Comment: aws does not mention anything about a throughput limit look like I was wrong (bad doc reading sorry) However, it does not guarantee what throughput you are going to get so there is a limit per GET request depending on the network condition (which is best effort). AWS claim that a single instance can go up to 100  GB/s. Maybe this is the answer? https://medium.com/@venks.sa/copying-data-from-s3-to-ebs-30x-faster-using-go-e2cdb1093284

Answer (score 1):

Having 10Gbps doesn't guarantee that the other end is sending data to you at that speed.

Prior to [current-generation EC2 instance types configured with ENA](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/the-floodgates-are-open-increased-network-bandwidth-for-ec2-instances/), which support up to 25 Gbps to S3, the maximum was 5 Gbps.

You could do a couple of additional tests, for example EC2 to EC2 or EC2 to speedtest.net (or equivalent).

By the way, if you genuinely are downloading a 1.75GB text file then compression would help.

Comment: speedtest-cli gives me 850.94 Mbit/s. (see post update)

Comment: Compression is under consideration, but it would give me a factor of 3x at most.

Comment: How often does the file's content change? How often do you need to download it? Have you looked at newer instance types with updated AMIs and ENA?

Comment: You mean these with gazzilion of cores such as m5a.24xlarge? Might be a bit out of my spending budget at the moment :)

Comment: files change rarely if ever. New files added - few times a day. EC2 instance might need to access files "randomly", but not often. ENA is installed, according to `modinfo ena`. OS - Latest Amazon Linux 2.

Answer (score 0):

The next time you find this problem try using the [dual-stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/dual-stack-endpoints.html) endpoints:

```
wget https://mybucket.s3.dualstack.amazonaws.com/myfile.txt
```

If that improves your speed, then the problem could be some IPv6 compatibility in the network path to the endpoint, like [broken AAAA records](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77418844/469294).

A solution then could be to change the DNS service you are using, or use the dual-stack endpoints in your CLI with:

```
aws configure set default.s3.use_dualstack_endpoint true
aws configure set default.s3.addressing_style virtual
```

or in the app using the [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/dual-stack-endpoints.html#dual-stack-endpoints-sdks).