# aws s3 access timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have noted recently that basic access to AWS S3 is giving timeout from my workstation. I use `aws s3 ls` for testing because it is a simple operation:

```
$ aws s3 ls --debug
...
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4420b24850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
...
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "awscli/clidriver.py", line 460, in main
  File "awscli/customizations/commands.py", line 151, in __call__
  File "awscli/customizations/commands.py", line 205, in __call__
  File "awscli/customizations/s3/subcommands.py", line 505, in _run_main
  File "awscli/customizations/s3/subcommands.py", line 570, in _list_all_buckets
  File "awscli/botocore/client.py", line 341, in _api_call
  File "awscli/botocore/client.py", line 683, in _make_api_call
  File "awscli/botocore/client.py", line 703, in _make_request
  File "awscli/botocore/endpoint.py", line 101, in make_request
  File "awscli/botocore/endpoint.py", line 155, in _send_request
  File "awscli/botocore/endpoint.py", line 199, in _do_get_response
  File "awscli/botocore/endpoint.py", line 271, in _send
  File "awscli/botocore/httpsession.py", line 477, in send
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

curiously, **wget** takes 17 minutes to get one answer from that endpoint:

```
$ time wget --debug https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
...
Resolving s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)... 64:ff9b::34d8:2460, 64:ff9b::34d8:ddc8, 64:ff9b::34d8:fba6, ...
Caching s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com => 64:ff9b::34d8:2460 64:ff9b::34d8:ddc8 64:ff9b::34d8:fba6 64:ff9b::36e7:8550 64:ff9b::34d8:d170 64:ff9b::34d9:8578 64:ff9b::34d8:3d40 64:ff9b::36e7:aa98 52.216.209.112 52.216.251.166 54.231.170.152 54.231.133.80 52.216.221.200 52.216.36.96 52.217.133.120 52.216.61.64
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|64:ff9b::34d8:2460|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|64:ff9b::34d8:ddc8|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|64:ff9b::34d8:fba6|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|64:ff9b::36e7:8550|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|64:ff9b::34d8:d170|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|64:ff9b::34d9:8578|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|64:ff9b::34d8:3d40|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|64:ff9b::36e7:aa98|:443... Closed fd 3
failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com)|52.216.209.112|:443... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000560df7694100 (new refcount 1).
... 

real    17m29,487s
user    0m0,022s
sys 0m0,013s
```

while **curl** returns a quick answer:

```
curl -v https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
*   Trying 64:ff9b::34d8:22a0:443...
*   Trying 52.216.29.166:443...
* Connected to s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (52.216.29.166) port 443 (#0)
...
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com left intact

real    0m0,855s
user    0m0,095s
sys 0m0,008s
```

What is the cause ?

Answer (score 2):

The cause seems to be that the DNS server is returning [broken AAAA records](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8305.html#section-7.2). Those are IPv6 addresses that can not be reached. In that case they have the prefix `64:ff9b::`, so they are [special addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Special_addresses) dedicated for IPv4/IPv6 translation.

Why is that translation needed ? Maybe because the endpoint `s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` is  IPv4 only and somewhere in the path to the servers there is an IPv6-only network.

That means that a DNS service might have translated the *IPv4* addresses to *IPv6* ([DNS64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6147)?) but some  routing device is not able to translate it back to *IPv4* ([NAT64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6146)?).

AWS provides [dual-stacks endpoints for AWS S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/dual-stack-endpoints.html) that prevent this problem. For example, the endpoint `s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` might be accessed quickly because provides real IPv6 addresses:

```
$ time wget -6 --debug https://s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
....
real    0m0,789s
user    0m0,019s
sys     0m0,014s
```

In order to use the CLI with the dual-stack endpoints execute:

```
aws configure set default.s3.use_dualstack_endpoint true
aws configure set default.s3.addressing_style virtual
```

they can also be used by applications via the [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/dual-stack-endpoints.html#dual-stack-endpoints-sdks) and the [REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RESTAPI.html).